# ACS/Facebook Integration - ACS40001: An error occurred while attempting to get an access token from Facebook

Tags: facebook, azure, wif, acs

Getting the following error setting up ACS/Facebook integration:

> HTTP Error Code:   502 Message:    ACS40000: An error occurred while
>   processing a Facebook sign-in response. This may be caused by invalid
>   configuration of the Facebook application. Inner Message:  ACS40001:
>   An error occurred while attempting to get an access token from
>   Facebook. Inner Message:   ACS90005: Web exception Trace ID:
>   988ec1a7-e02b-4dcf-abab-51812745a121 Timestamp:    2011-07-12 19:59:51Z

I've verified that App ID, App Secret, Site URL and Site Domain have all been set.

For Site Url, we're using **https://project.accesscontrol.windows.net**

For Site Domain, we're using **project.accesscontrol.windows.net**

I'm using the following as a guideline:

http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/steve/archive/2011/04/21/windows-azure-access-control-services-federation-with-facebook.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

http://www.leastprivilege.com/AccessControlServiceV2AndFacebookIntegration.aspx

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked my (working) settings. Differences I see:

- I did not enter a Site Domain over at Facebook
- On the ACS side, I have "Application permissions" set to "email" (not sure if you have something entered there?)

Comment: Thanks... not sure what the issue was but re-generating the application secret and syncing it w/ ACS management portal seemed to have fixed it.